# Cucumber with springboot2.6.5 doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, cucumber, spring-test

I found a strange problem. When I use springboot 2.6.5 + 7.3.8 cucumber, the console prints the cucumber logs but not the springboot logs and it does not run any of the scenario.
I tried to run springtest with just junit which is fine and tested that the feature resources are addressed correctly, but I still have this problem. And when I comment out @springtest and @CucumberContextConfiguration, cucumber still runs and  doesn't report any errors.
MainTestclass:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"classpath:features"},
        glue = {"com.my.example.project.step"},
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/html-reports.htm"}
)
public class ApplicationTest {

}
```

cucumber config

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SpringTestConfig.class, MockObjectConfiguration.class})
public class CucumberSpringContextConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private List<Resetable> resetables;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(resetables).stream().forEach(v -> v.reset());
    }
}
```

Spring test config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.my.example.project"},
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,classes = ComponentNotScanInTest.class),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,pattern = ".*\\.helper\\..*"),
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,pattern = ".*\\.infrastructure\\.persistence\\repository\\..*")
        }
)
public class SpringTestConfig {
}
```

[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj3Hn.png)

I hope it can start with spring test

Comment: What does your package structure look like?